# Using Oracle Coherence as second level cache for IBatis in Grails app

Tags: caching, grails, grails-orm, ibatis, oracle-coherence

In a Grails app that's using IBatis for ORM (rather than GORM/Hibernate), is it possible to specify Oracle Coherence as a second level cache for IBatis? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/akhil/mybatis-coherence is unit tested for the spec.
Never tried with grails.